# Casella and Berger possible typo?

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function

I am following a Casella and Berger's proof but I have a difficulties to understand one particular step.

Assuming that $X_1,...,X_n$ is a **random sample** (i.i.d.) drawn from a $N(0,1)$ distribution, they estimate the joint distribution of the following transformation:

$y_1=\overline{x}$

$y_2=x_2-\overline{x}$

...

$y_n=x_n-\overline{x}$

I know that in order to obtain the pdf of the transformation we have to calculate the inverse of the transformation, calculate the  determinant of the Jacobian, etc.

What I obtain after doing all the procedure is that the joint probability distribution of the transformation is:

$$\frac{n}{{(2\pi)}^{\frac{n}2}}e^{-1/2(y_1-\frac{1}n\sum_2^n(y_i+y_1))^2}e^{-1/2(\sum_2^n(y_i+y_1))^2}$$

since $y_1=\frac{1}n\sum_1^nx_i$ we have that $x_1=y_1-\frac{1}n\sum_2^n(y_i+y_1)$ which is equal to $x_1=\frac{1}n(y_1-\sum_2^ny_i)$

and hence the final expression would be:
$$\frac{n}{{(2\pi)}^{\frac{n}2}}e^{-1/2(\frac{1}n(y_1-\sum_2^ny_i))^2}e^{-1/2(\sum_2^n(y_i+y_1))^2}$$

Well, actually if you see the theorem 5.3.1 from Casella and Berger's "Statistical Inference" they write:

$$\frac{n}{{(2\pi)}^{\frac{n}2}}e^{-1/2((y_1-\sum_2^ny_i))^2}e^{-1/2(\sum_2^n(y_i+y_1))^2}$$  (without the $\frac{1}n$ on the first exponential)

Is that a typo or did I make some mistake?

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you specified _what_ the two statistics in question are.

Comment: I'll edit my question since actually I am interested in obtaining the joint pdf of the transformation, the rest of the proof is straightforward.

Comment: @StubbornAtom my bad , it's actually the sample mean

Comment: See if page 3 of http://jekyll.math.byuh.edu/courses/m321/handouts/mean_var_indep.pdf helps.

Comment: @Clarinetist thanks! I'll give it a look

Comment: My copy shows the Jacobian = 1/n, but I calculate n, which is the assertion here: http://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall18/sta611.01/Lecture/lec12_mean_var_indep.pdf. is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the assertion: $x_1=y_1-\frac{1}n\sum_2^n(y_i+y_1)$. Since $y_1=\frac1n\sum_1^n x_i$, this means:
$$\sum x_i = ny_1$$ and so
$$x_1 = ny_1 - \sum_2^n x_i=ny_1-\sum_2^n (y_i + y_1)=y_1 - \sum_2^n y_i.$$
Your calculation introduced a factor of $\frac1n$, or it dropped the factor of $n$.

Comment: You are right , when I extracted the $x_1$ from the summation , I forgot to write the $\frac{1}m$ that multiplies it. Thanks!